# Orleans 7.0 Serializer not working with POCOs originating from Nuget package

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, orleans

I have a Orleans 7.0 project with and I'm having an issue with the new default serializer.

The old serializer in Orleans 3.6.5 worked fine and it was serializing all the models and Dtos in the several internal Nuget packages.

Now in Orleans 7.0 the project does not recognize the models in the Nuget packages and I get this error:

```
Orleans.Serialization.CodecNotFoundException: Could not find a copier for type InternalProject.Model.
   at Orleans.Serialization.Serializers.CodecProvider.ThrowCopierNotFound(Type type) in /_/src/Orleans.Serialization/Serializers/CodecProvider.cs:line 666
   at Orleans.Serialization.Serializers.CodecProvider.GetDeepCopier[T]() in /_/src/Orleans.Serialization/Serializers/CodecProvider.cs:line 300
   at Orleans.Serialization.ServiceCollectionExtensions.CopierHolder`1.get_Value() in /_/src/Orleans.Serialization/Hosting/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs:line 203
   at Orleans.Serialization.GeneratedCodeHelpers.OrleansGeneratedCodeHelper.GetService[TService](Object caller, ICodecProvider codecProvider) in /_/src/Orleans.Serialization/GeneratedCodeHelpers/OrleansGeneratedCodeHelper.cs:lin
e 75
   at OrleansCodeGen.InternalProject.Model.Copier_SpecificModel..ctor(ICodecProvider codecProvider) in C:\Projects\InternalProject.Model\Orleans.CodeGenerator\Orleans.CodeGenerator.Orle
ansSerializationSourceGenerator\InternalProject.Model.orleans.g.cs:line 20736
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.ConstructorInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Orleans.Serialization.GeneratedCodeHelpers.OrleansGeneratedCodeHelper.GetService[TService](Object caller, ICodecProvider codecProvider) in /_/src/Orleans.Serialization/GeneratedCodeHelpers/OrleansGeneratedCodeHelper.cs:lin
e 72
```

Now for the interesting part: when I copy paste the exact same class in my main project I no longer get this error, and the class serializes perfectly fine.

I tried referencing the Nuget project directly in the main project(ProjectReference), the result is the same.

I only get rid of errors in two scenarios:

1. when I use the Json Serializer with IgnoreCycles (undesirable in my scenario, doesn't get rid of the underlying problem)

```
siloBuilder.Services.AddSerializer(sb =>
                    {
                        sb.AddJsonSerializer(
                            isSupported: type => type.Namespace.StartsWith("Nuget.Namespace"),
                            new JsonSerializerOptions()
                            {
                                ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles
                            }
                        );
                    });
```

2. when I add the classes directly in the main project. Example class from the error:

```
[GenerateSerializer]
    public sealed class Class1: Class1Base
    {
        public Class1()
        {
            
        }

        public Class1(IRequest request, bool boolean, InternalClass internalClass) 
            : base(request, boolean)
        {
            InternalClass = internalClass;
        }

        [Id(0)]
        public InternalClass InternalClass{ get; set; }
        
    }

   [GenerateSerializer]
    public class Class1Base
    {
        public Class1Base()
        {
            
        }
        public Class1Base(IRequest request, bool boolean)
        {
            Request = request;
            Boolean= boolean;
        }

        [Id(0)]
        public IRequest Request { get; set; }
        [Id(1)]
        public bool Boolean{ get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I have the same problems, I have been working on that for last 5 days and simply can't find a solution, and copy-pasting 200 classes is a stupid option...

Answer (score 6):

The Orleans serializer has a lot of performance and flexibility benefits, but as you have discovered it comes with a very hard edge around the use of 3rd party types. You have a few options, none of which are great

1. Continue to use the 3rd party types and define surrogates and codecs for every type in that you will be serializing. This can be a very heavy lift and probably not the best idea. [See this document for how to do that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/orleans/host/configuration-guide/serialization?pivots=orleans-7-0#surrogates-for-serializing-foreign-types), but be advised that that if you accidentally miss a type in the graph, it will blow up at runtime, so be sure your tests are good.
2. Use a different serializer. Orleans ships with Json based serializers that are much easier to work with. They might not be quite as fast as the Orleans Serializer, but they are much simpler to get running. This is the simplest choice and has very few downsides. [See this article on how to do that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/orleans/host/configuration-guide/serialization-configuration?pivots=orleans-7-0)
3. Remove the 3rd party types from your DTOs. In this option, you alter your grain contracts so that you only use 1st party types (those you define yourself) to send messages between grains. This is less convenient and removes some of the magic of Orleans' object transparency but removes the issue. This is the option that I choose in my case because I think it keeps my model cleaner.

I also suspect it might be possible, with a lot of effort, to write a Source Generator that can automatically walk the object graphs used in your grain calls and auto generate codecs and surrogates for 3rd party types to remove this problem completely. But I didn't find that necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working for netstandard2.x project by installing the following nuget packages directly on the project:

```
Microsoft.Orleans.CodeGenerator
Microsoft.Orleans.Serialization
```